# How can I extract a last name from full name in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with fullname column.  I want to make a query for finding a person via his last name but his last name is in the full name column.

Comment: Try: `WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(fullname, " ", -1) = 'lastname'` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)  Or consider storing the first and last names in separate fields.

Comment: Can you show some examples? It's hard to know what to do unless we know, for example, whether `fullname` looks like `John Q. Public`, or maybe `Public, John Q.` or whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

Would it matter if it accidentally returned someone whose first name matched your query?

A simple query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE fullname LIKE '%insertlastname%'
```

If you want to define the last name as the name after the last space:

```
SELECT substring_index(fullname, ' ', -1) as lastname
FROM TABLE
WHERE lastname='insertlastname'
```

Two suboptimal answers, but some answers at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you want to fetch by query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `fullname` , ' ', 2 ),' ',1) AS b, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `fullname` , ' ', -1 ),' ',2) AS c FROM `users` WHERE `userid`='1'
```

But you can also try by PHP to fetch last name. You just use explode function to fetch last name.

Exm:

```
$full_name = "row moin";
$pieces = explode(" ", $fullname);
echo $first_name = $pieces[0]; // row
echo $last_name =  $pieces[1]; // moin
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer for this is like this suppose we have a name

> Charles Dickens

:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(FULLNAME,' ',-1) like '%Dickens';
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t.ContactName, 
  SUBSTRING(
    t.ContactName, 
    CHARINDEX(' ', t.ContactName) + 1, 
    (DATALENGTH(t.ContactName) - CHARINDEX(' ', t.ContactName)) + 1
  ) AS last_name
    FROM dbo.t_w3_schools_customers AS t
    ORDER BY 1;
```